# Logic doesn't work in this method overloading example

Tags: java, overloading

I'm sudying java from the Pluralsigh.com. Code below is written by me to follow the video lessons. The topic is method overloading. The code seem to not increment the passenger count as soon as I implement the hasCarryOnSpace method. I call this method inside the add1Passanger(int bags, int carryOns) method after the if statement. I also call it inside the add1Passenger(Passanger p, int carryOns) method. Please tell me what's wrong with my logic...

```
public class Flight {

    //fields
    public int passengers;
    private int seats = 150;
    private int checkedBags;
    private int maxCarryOns = checkedBags*2, totalCarryOns;
    private int freeCheckedBags;

    //getter/setters
    public int getSeats(){return 150;}
    public int getCheckedBags() {return this.checkedBags;}

    //constructors
    public Flight (){}  
    public Flight(int freeCheckedBags) {
        this.freeCheckedBags=freeCheckedBags;
    }   
    public Flight(int freeCheckedBags, int checkedBags) {
        this(freeCheckedBags); 
        this.checkedBags=checkedBags;
    }


    //methods   
    public void addPassengers(Passenger... list) {
        if(hasSeats(list.length)) {
            passengers += list.length;
            for(Passenger passanger: list) {
                checkedBags += passanger.getCheckedBags();
            }
        }
        else tooMany(); 
    }

    public void add1Passenger(){
        if(hasSeats())
            passengers +=1;
        else tooMany();
        return;
    }

    public void add1Passanger(int bags){
        if(hasSeats()) {
            add1Passenger();
            this.checkedBags+=bags;
        }
    }

    public void add1Passenger(Passenger p){
        add1Passanger(p.getCheckedBags());
    }

    public void add1Passenger(int bags, int carryOns){
        if(hasSeats() && hasCarryOnSpace(carryOns)){
            add1Passanger(bags);
            totalCarryOns+=carryOns;
        }
    }

    public void add1Passenger(Passenger p, int carryOns){
        add1Passenger(p.getCheckedBags(), carryOns);
    }

    public boolean hasCarryOnSpace(int carryOns){
        return totalCarryOns+carryOns < maxCarryOns;
    }

    public boolean hasSeats(){
        return passengers < getSeats();
    }

    private boolean hasSeats(int count) {
        return passengers+count <= seats;
    }

    private void tooMany(){
        System.out.println("no more seats available");
    }

    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args ){
        Flight usAir = new Flight();
        //i have a separate Passenger class created w/ freeBags as first
        //parameter and checkedBags as the second in its constructors
        Passenger bob = new Passenger();
        Passenger jean = new Passenger(0, 1);       
        Passenger nick = new Passenger(0, 2);
        Passenger dan = new Passenger(2,2);

        usAir.addPassengers(bob, jean);
        usAir.add1Passenger(dan);
        usAir.add1Passenger();
        usAir.add1Passanger(2);
        //calls below don't increment the passenger count
        usAir.add1Passenger(nick, 2);
        usAir.add1Passenger(1, 1);
        System.out.println("usAir has " + usAir.passengers 
                + " passengers " + "with " + usAir.getCheckedBags()+
                " checked bags,"+" "+usAir.freeCheckedBags
                +" free bags, and "+usAir.totalCarryOns+" carryOns on board");
   }
}
```

Comment: private int maxCarryOns = checkedBags*2, totalCarryOns;
looks like it will be 0 as checkedBags is an uninitialised int (and therefore 0) when the code reaches this line.

Comment: There is quite a lot wrong with this code really.For example, the fact that there are 150 seats is stored in two separate places, both of which are referenced.

Comment: Are you sure it should be `add1Passanger` instead of `add1Passenger`?  Remember, spelling counts.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark Chorley. This code is meant for learning purposes. I'm a beginner, and not a native speaker either. Your first comment however helped me fix my mistake. Instead of writing private int maxCarryOns = checkedBags*2, totalCarryOns; i wrote private int maxCarryOns = seats*2, totalCarryOns; that solved half the problem. I then had to update all methods that involved the Passenger type to increment freeChekedBags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following code. Read comments for explanations. The purpose of the code is not only to answer the question, but also demonstrate the idea of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

By posting an MCVE you are more likely to get better and quicker help,  and, far more important: in many cases it helps you find the problem yourself.

```
public class Flight {

    //fields
    public int passengers;
    private int seats = 150;
    private int checkedBags;

    //The problem is here:  maxCarryOns in intialized to 0.
    //private int maxCarryOns = checkedBags*2;
    //change to say:
    private int maxCarryOns = seats*2;

    private int totalCarryOns;
    private int freeCheckedBags;

    //getter/setters
    public int getSeats(){return 150;}
    public int getCheckedBags() {return checkedBags;}

    //constructors
    public Flight (){}

   //removed 2 more constructors , not needed to demonstrate the problem


    //methods

    //removed, not needed to demonstrate the problem
    //public void addPassengers(Passenger... list) {

    public void add1Passenger(){
        if(hasSeats()) {
            passengers +=1;
        } else {
            tooMany();
        }
        return;
    }

    public void add1Passanger(int bags){
        if(hasSeats()) {
            add1Passenger();
            checkedBags+=bags;
        }
    }

    //removed, not needed to demonstrate the problem
    //public void add1Passenger(Passenger p)

    public void add1Passenger(int bags, int carryOns){

        if(hasSeats() && hasCarryOnSpace(carryOns)){

            add1Passanger(bags);
            totalCarryOns+=carryOns;
        }
    }

    public void add1Passenger(Passenger p, int carryOns){

        add1Passenger(p.getCheckedBags(), carryOns);
    }

    public boolean hasCarryOnSpace(int carryOns){

        //a simple printout here would hae revealed that 
        //maxCarryOns was 0, hencethis methos always returned false.
        return (totalCarryOns+carryOns) < maxCarryOns;
    }

    public boolean hasSeats(){

        return passengers < getSeats();
    }

    //removed, not needed to demonstrate the problem
    //private boolean hasSeats(int count) {

    private void tooMany(){
        System.out.println("no more seats available");
    }

    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args ){

        Flight usAir = new Flight();

        //removed all statements which are not needed to demonstrate the problem
        Passenger nick = new Passenger(0,2);

        //calls below don't increment the passenger count
        usAir.add1Passenger(nick, 2);
        usAir.add1Passenger(1, 1);
        System.out.println("usAir has " + usAir.passengers
                + " passengers " + "with " + usAir.getCheckedBags()+
                " checked bags,"+" "+usAir.freeCheckedBags
                +" free bags, and "+usAir.totalCarryOns+" carryOns on board");
   }
}

//include all needed to run the code
class Passenger {

    int freeBags =0, checkedBags =0;

    Passenger(int freeBags, int checkedBags){

        this.freeBags = freeBags;
        this.checkedBags = checkedBags;
    }

    /**
     *@return
     */
    public int getCheckedBags() {

        return  checkedBags;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Although the code should be much concise and clean for this scenario.. its just first guess assign 0 to `passenger` in the `Flight` construction

Comment: This is wrong. The problem is that maxCarryOns is set to 0.